# a jQuery show() that accepts a value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a shorter way to write this?

```
if (someBool) {
    $dom.show();
} else {
    $dom.hide();
}
```

jQuery's toggleClass function can be called like `toggleClass('class', someBool)` to add or remove the class depending on the value of someBool. I'm looking for a function like that in jQuery for showing/hiding elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very similar to `toggleClass`:

```
$('selector').toggle(someBool);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unsurprisingly, [`$dom.toggle(someBool)`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) should work.

Answer (score 0):

.toggle() already behaves as a bool. If it's hidden, it makes it visible and vice versa. No parameter needed unless you specifically need the bool for something else.

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  $dom.toggle(someBool);
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that toggle would be a good alternative. But just in case you meant your question literally...

```
 someBool ? $dom.show() : $dom.hide();
```